# Different type of input method open for different type value select from dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am not getting how we can write JavaScript code for changing the input type method if user select different type of value from the drop-down list please help me.

E.g

If user Select Title, Claim etc from drop-down list then simple text input format open in front drop-down list in HTML

if user select Application_date of another date type then Date range input type open in front of drop-down list in HTML etc

And please tell me how we can store value in a variable in PHP Please help

HTML code

```
<select id="S1value" name="S1value" >
    <option value="Claim"  >Claim - C</option>
    <option value="Title"  >Title - T</option>
    <option value="Description"  >Description - D</option>
    <option value="Abstract" >Abstract - A</option>
    <option value="Application_No"  >Application_Number -APN</option>
    <option value="Priority_Number"  >Priority_Number - PN</option>
    <option value="Record_Number"  >Record_Number - RN</option>
    <option value="Priority_Date" >Priority_Date - PD</option>
    <option value="Application_Date"  >Application_Date -APD</option>
    <option value="Publication_Date"  >Publication_Date - PD</option>
    <option value="US_Class">US_Class - USC</option>
    <option value="IPC_Class">IPC_Class - IPC</option>
    <option value="CPC_Class">CPC_Class - CPC</option>
    <option value="Priority_Country_Code"  >Priority Country Code - PCC</option>
    <option value="Designate_States"  >Designate_States - DS</option>
    <option value="Legal_Status_Current"  >Legal_Status_Current - LSC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The above dropdown is static or dynamic ?

Comment: static but input type dependent on value select from drop-down list if user select date value then input type date range open etc

Answer (score 1):

I have just added code. To display datepicker you need to add code for this. Bu input will be added based on your selection.

```js
function addInput(expression){
  switch(expression) {
    case "text":
        $("#S1value").after('<input class="input form-control" type="text">');
        break;
    case "date":
        $("#S1value").after('<input class="input form-control" type="date">');
        break;
    default:
        $("#S1value").after('<input class="input form-control" type="text">');        
  } 
}

$("#S1value").on("change",function(){
  $("input").remove();
  addInput($(this).find("option:selected").attr('inputtype'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="S1value" name="S1value" >
<option value="Claim" inputtype="text" >Claim - C</option>
<option value="Title"  inputtype="text">Title - T</option>
<option value="Description" inputtype="text" >Description - D</option>
<option value="Abstract" inputtype="text">Abstract - A</option>
<option value="Application_No"  inputtype="text">Application_Number - APN</option>
<option value="Priority_Number"  inputtype="text">Priority_Number - PN</option>
<option value="Record_Number"  inputtype="text">Record_Number - RN</option>
<option value="Priority_Date" inputtype="text">Priority_Date - PD</option>
<option value="Application_Date" inputtype="date" >Application_Date - APD</option>
<option value="Publication_Date"  >Publication_Date - PD</option>
<option value="US_Class" inputtype="text">US_Class - USC</option>
<option value="IPC_Class"  inputtype="text">IPC_Class - IPC</option>
<option value="CPC_Class" inputtype="text" >CPC_Class - CPC</option>
<option value="Priority_Country_Code" inputtype="text" >Priority Country Code - PCC</option>
<option value="Designate_States"  inputtype="text">Designate_States - DS</option>
<option value="Legal_Status_Current"  inputtype="text">Legal_Status_Current - LSC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Or you can add an attribute on <option value="Claim" inputType="datepicker"  >Claim - C</option>  and write common switch case based on $("#S1value option:selected").attr('inputType');

Comment: if user select date type from drop-down list the input type date range open

Answer (score 1):

have a custom data attribute which will tell what will be the target type

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> Sample Code </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<select id="S1value" name="S1value" onChange="createInput()" >
        <option data-type="text" value="Claim"  >Claim - C</option>
        <option data-type="text" value="Title"  >Title - T</option>
        <option data-type="text" value="Description"  >Description - D</option>
        <option data-type="text" value="Abstract" >Abstract - A</option>
        <option data-type="text" value="Application_No"  >Application_Number - APN</option>
        <option data-type="text" value="Priority_Number"  >Priority_Number - PN</option>
        <option data-type="text" value="Record_Number"  >Record_Number - RN</option>
        <option data-type="date" value="Priority_Date" >Priority_Date - PD</option>
        <option data-type="date" value="Application_Date"  >Application_Date - APD</option>
        <option data-type="date" value="Publication_Date"  >Publication_Date - PD</option>
        <option data-type="text" value="US_Class" >US_Class - USC</option>
        <option data-type="text" value="IPC_Class"  >IPC_Class - IPC</option>
        <option data-type="text" value="CPC_Class"  >CPC_Class - CPC</option>
        <option data-type="text" value="Priority_Country_Code"  >Priority Country Code - PCC</option>
        <option data-type="text" value="Designate_States"  >Designate_States - DS</option>
        <option data-type="text" value="Legal_Status_Current"  >Legal_Status_Current - LSC</option>
</select>

<span id="inputElementWrapper" ></span>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
       function createInput(){
           var type = $('#S1value').find(':selected').data('type');
               var input = document.createElement('input');
               input.type=type;
               input.name = "option";
               $('#inputElementWrapper').html("");
               $('#inputElementWrapper').append(input);
       }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to store value of drop-down list and input type in variables ? please help

Comment: you can get the value of the drop-down list like $('#S1value'),val().and if you want to store the data inside php means you need to have this form inside a form element with method and action property.on submitting the form the values will be passed to the file mentioned in the action and then you can store it

Comment: I want to give date range in input date how we can improve this

Comment: You can use JQuery UI date picker or there are so many plugins available out there like datetimepicker

Comment: how to store input value in variable ? and on default drop-down list why it is not showing input field ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put an input after select tag.
then use jQuery given below.

```js
$("#S1value").on("change",function(){
 var value = $(this).val();
 switch(value) {
  case "Title":
   $("#input-select").attr("type","text");
   break;
  case "Application_Date":
   $("#input-select").attr("type","date");
   break;
  default:
  $("#input-select").attr("type","text");
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="S1value" name="S1value" >
<option value="Claim"  >Claim - C</option>
<option value="Title"  >Title - T</option>
<option value="Description"  >Description - D</option>
<option value="Abstract" >Abstract - A</option>
<option value="Application_No"  >Application_Number - APN</option>
<option value="Priority_Number"  >Priority_Number - PN</option>
<option value="Record_Number"  >Record_Number - RN</option>
<option value="Priority_Date" >Priority_Date - PD</option>
<option value="Application_Date"  >Application_Date - APD</option>
<option value="Publication_Date"  >Publication_Date - PD</option>
<option value="US_Class" >US_Class - USC</option>
<option value="IPC_Class"  >IPC_Class - IPC</option>
<option value="CPC_Class"  >CPC_Class - CPC</option>
<option value="Priority_Country_Code"  >Priority Country Code - PCC</option>
<option value="Designate_States"  >Designate_States - DS</option>
<option value="Legal_Status_Current"  >Legal_Status_Current - LSC</option>
</select>
<input class="input form-control" id="input-select" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch statement to show the controls you want.

Using the code below when you post your form, the values will be available as `$_Post[Name]` where name will be the value of the selected option.

So you can use:

```
$S1value = $_Post["Name"];
$S1input = $_Post[$S1value];
```

Since you have a date range for `Application_Date` you will have two inputs if that is the selected option:

```
$S1value = $_Post["Name"];
$S1input = $_Post["Application_Date"];
$S1input2 = $_Post["Application_Date_2"];
```

```js
function showinput() {
  var value = $("#S1value").val();
  var txt= value.replace(/\_/g, " ");
  var label = $("<label />").attr("for", value).html(txt + ": ");
  switch (value) {
    case "Application_Date":
      var input = $("<input />").attr("type", "text").attr("name", value);
      var input2 = $("<input />").attr("type", "text").attr("name", value + "_2");
      label.append("From: ")
      label.append(input);
      label.append(" To: ");
      label.append(input2);
      $('#beforeSelect').html('').append(label);
      break;
  default:

      var input = $("<input />").attr("type", "text").attr("id", value);
      label.append(input);

 }
  $('#beforeSelect').html('').append(label);
  
}

$("#S1value").on("change", function() {
   showinput();
  
});
 showinput();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="S1value" name="S1value">
<option value="Claim"  >Claim - C</option>
<option value="Title"  >Title - T</option>
<option value="Description"  >Description - D</option>
<option value="Abstract" >Abstract - A</option>
<option value="Application_No"  >Application_Number - APN</option>
<option value="Priority_Number"  >Priority_Number - PN</option>
<option value="Record_Number"  >Record_Number - RN</option>
<option value="Priority_Date" >Priority_Date - PD</option>
<option value="Application_Date"  >Application_Date - APD</option>
<option value="Publication_Date"  >Publication_Date - PD</option>
<option value="US_Class" >US_Class - USC</option>
<option value="IPC_Class"  >IPC_Class - IPC</option>
<option value="CPC_Class"  >CPC_Class - CPC</option>
<option value="Priority_Country_Code"  >Priority Country Code - PCC</option>
<option value="Designate_States"  >Designate_States - DS</option>
<option value="Legal_Status_Current"  >Legal_Status_Current - LSC</option>
</select>

<div id="beforeSelect"></div>
```

Comment: I want to remove the printing value of text near input method how ?

Comment: Just change this: `var label = $("<label />").attr("for", value).html(txt + ": ");` to this: `var label = $("<label />").attr("for", value);`

Comment: Why it is not working if i put html code inside <from > and script code inside body when i am opening local host it is not working ?                     pllease help

Comment: That's an entirely different question unrelated to this. Feel free to open up a new question showing your complete code and what errors you are getting.

Comment: How we can print dropdown and input box same line and how we can give the space between them please tell me ?

Comment: How we can store value with variable instead of value name as      
                                                                                                      
 
$S1input = $_Post["Application_Date"];
$S1input2 = $_Post["Application_Date_2"];                                                                                       Application_Date and Application_Date_2     if we use name then we need more variable for every date if we use variable it will  be easy ? please help

Comment: how to print drop-down and input box for text and date range in same line please please help ????

Comment: This is not working $S1value = $_Post["Name"];                                                   can u help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with one more solution https://jsfiddle.net/6gaagjze/

```js
$('#S1value').change(function(){
 $("input").remove();
 if($(this).val().indexOf('Date') < 0){
   $('#S1value').parent().prepend('<input type="text" />');
  }else{
   $('#S1value').parent().prepend('<input type="date" />');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="S1value" name="S1value" >
    <option value="Claim"  >Claim - C</option>
    <option value="Title"  >Title - T</option>
    <option value="Description"  >Description - D</option>
    <option value="Abstract" >Abstract - A</option>
    <option value="Application_No"  >Application_Number -APN</option>
    <option value="Priority_Number"  >Priority_Number - PN</option>
    <option value="Record_Number"  >Record_Number - RN</option>
    <option value="Priority_Date" >Priority_Date - PD</option>
    <option value="Application_Date"  >Application_Date -APD</option>
    <option value="Publication_Date"  >Publication_Date - PD</option>
    <option value="US_Class">US_Class - USC</option>
    <option value="IPC_Class">IPC_Class - IPC</option>
    <option value="CPC_Class">CPC_Class - CPC</option>
    <option value="Priority_Country_Code"  >Priority Country Code - PCC</option>
    <option value="Designate_States"  >Designate_States - DS</option>
    <option value="Legal_Status_Current"  >Legal_Status_Current - LSC</option>
</select>
```